# Cannot find connected accessory if EAAccessoryManager.shared() is called in AppDelegate constructor

Tags: ios, swift, external-accessory, eaaccessory

If I call EAAccessoryManager.shared() inside the AppDelegate constructor e.g.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var accessoryManager = EAAccessoryManager.shared()

  ...

  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,  
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  ...
}
```

Then later I access the accessory manager to get connected accessories (with an accessory connected) **EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories.count** returns 0, which is incorrect.

If I don't call EAAccessoryManager.shared() in the AppDelegate constructor, then **EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories.count** returns 1, which is correct.

I can workaround this problem, but I really wanted to understand why this might be happening, as I could have misunderstood something about how the EAAccessoryManager is meant to work (or perhaps something more fundamental about how an app is initialised - I am new to iOS programming).

Has anyone hit this problem before, or maybe have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: I don't know the cause (maybe calling it too soon causes an issue) but what's the point of storing a reference to `EAAccessoryManager.shared()` in a property?

Comment: In the real code I was creating a more complex object which used EAAccessoryManager.shared(), but I simplified the code down to isolate the problem.

Comment: Any solution for this? Me too having the same problem.